# What is the purpose of new DAYS() function in Excel 2013?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I just found out that Excel 2013 has a DAYS() worksheet function. It appears to function exactly the same as subtracting one date from another.

One of the blogs I visited said that DAYS() permits you to work with text strings as dates, but I found that text strings also work with subtraction, as in:

```
="7/15/2016"-"7/1/2016"
```

which results in 14 when I enter it, which is the same result as

```
=DAYS("7/15/2016","7/1/2016")
```

Does anyone know what DAYS() will do that date subtraction will not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Days can be more dynamic for example you could create a more complex formula with dynamic variables like this =DAYS(VLOOKUP(C3,C5:E16,3,FALSE),B3). In the example you sent it is more common for them to be static. Using the cells themselves can provide a similar function assuming they are in the same date and number formats. So an example using the same formula as above would be =VLOOKUP(C3,C5:E16,3,FALSE)-B3.

Comment: As I mentioned in my OP, `="11/30/2016"-"11/15/2016"` also returns 15. So I still don't see the advantage of DAYS().

Comment: @ vknowles I apologize. I have updated my answer with a more thorough response.

Comment: You haven't proven my point, but you have supported it. The `DAYS(VLOOKUP(...)` formula and the subtraction both produce the same result. So, again, what is the advantage of `DAYS()`?